# Putting If-else statement inside message.contains

Tags: kotlin, chatbot

I am trying to do a chatbot in Kotlin without using any frameworks because I am unclear on how to integrate the chatbot from the frameworks while still being able to connect to my SQL server database.

Below are my sample code:

```
message.contains("create budget") || message.contains("monthly budget") || message.contains("create budget for this month")-> {
                when (random) {
                    0 -> "Please provide me the full details in the correct order: Category with full name, Amount(RM) and Note with the delimiter of (;;)"
                    1 -> "Please enter full details in the correct order: Category with full name, Amount(RM) and Note with the delimiter of (;;)"
                    2 -> "Give me full details in the correct order: Category with full name, Amount(RM) and Note with the delimiter of (;;)"
                    else -> "error" }
// if-else statement here
            }
```

I would like to ask is it possible to put an if-else statement inside this message.contains? Inside the if-else statement, I will be putting condition to check whether the user input is acceptable before moving on to the next message.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? It is not a valid Kotlin code even without `if`.

Comment: Please show the surrounding code. (I'm guessing this is part of a larger `when` construct…?) And bear in mind that right now, it will use the return value of the `when (random)` block — but if you add further statements/values before the final `}` then it will use the last of those instead, discarding the result of the `when (random)`, which probably isn't what you want.